# Can I Select DISTINCT on 2 columns and Sum grouped by 1 column in one query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, count, distinct

Is it possible to write one query, where I would group by 2 columns in a table to get the count of total members plus get a sum of one column in that same table, but grouped by one column?

For example, the data looks like this

[image]

I want to get a count on distinct combinations of columns "OHID" and "MemID" and get the SUM of the "Amount" column grouped by OHID. The result is supposed to look like this

[image]

I was able to get the count correct using this query below

```
SELECT count(*) as TotCount
from (Select DISTINCT OHID, MemID
      from #temp) AS TotMembers
```

However, when I try to use this query below to get all the results together, I am getting a count of 15 and a totally different total sum.

```
SELECT t.OHID,
       count(TotMembers.MemID) as TotCount,
       sum(t.Amount) as TotalAmount
from (Select DISTINCT OHID, MemID
      from #temp) AS TotMembers
join #temp t on t.OHID =  TotMembers .OHID
GROUP by t.OHID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to consider `NULL` as a valid value.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select t.ohid,
       (count(distinct t.memid) +
        (case when count(*) <> count(t.memid) then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as num_memid,
       sum(t.amount) as total_amount
from #temp t
group by t.ohid,
```

The `case` logic might be a bit off-putting.  It is just adding `1` if any values are `NULL`.

You might find this easier to follow with two levels of aggregation:

```
select t.ohid, count(*), sum(amount)
from (select t.ohid, t.memid, sum(t.amount) as amount
      from #temp t
      group by t.ohid, t.memid
     ) t
group by t.ohid
```

Comment: Yes, the NULL will be a valid value for at least one row per each OHID. Your second query is working. I am trying to understand what you are doing with the two levels of aggregation.  I haven't tried the first one yet. Are there any pro & cons to the either approach? I will be using it with at least about 30,000 + records.

Comment: @Truecolor . . . If you set up a db/sql fiddle, it would be much simpler to test for typos.

Comment: Thanks. I just tested with Fiddle and the second query worked to populate the desired results.